# What's the host used by nuget package "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 OWIN Self Host 5.1.1"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, webserver, katana

What's the host/webserver that nuget package [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 OWIN Self Host 5.1.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/) uses to host webapi 2.1?

(following the Host dependencies in this page it does lead to [Katana server](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) but I wanted to make sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [OwinHttpListener](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener/OwinHttpListener.cs) that is a thin wrapper around HttpListener which in turn is a wrapper around Http.sys.

Comment: Cool, so this confirms that it uses Katana then. Thanks!